# Calling a different method from within main in java AND error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I have this code:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5621366/

But on line 56 , I have attempted to call the keyPressed method but when I attempt it I receive this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

This is quite a generic error with the java compiler , so I am unsure how to solve it.

FYI: I am a beginner to Java.

Also I get this error if I remove the 'new' do I need to import something?:

```
move.java:56: error: method keyPressed in class GraphicsProgram cannot be applie
d to given types;
                keyPressed();
                ^
  required: KeyEvent
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `new keyPressed();`. Take out the `new`, the only thing that can legally follow `new` is a constructor.

In order to make the square move in reaction to key presses, there are a few things that you'll need to change. Firstly, your program is not currently implementing the `KeyListener` interface. To implement this class, the code is as follows:

```
class GraphicsProgram extends Canvas implements KeyListener {
```

Secondly, since your class is now implementing an interface, you will need to override **all** of its abstract methods. Even though you're only using `keyPressed`, you will also need to override the methods `keyReleased` and `keyTyped` in order for the program to compile. Since you're not using them you can just leave them blank. Finally, you will have to set the graphics window as an action listener of itself. This can be done using the `addActionListener` method as such:

```
GP.addActionLisener( GP );
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this: move.java:56: error: method keyPressed in class GraphicsProgram cannot be applie
d to given types;
                keyPressed();
                ^
  required: KeyEvent
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: @Red_Hat Yes, you're not passing in any arguments for keyPressed, and it's expecting one. Why are you calling `keyPressed`? Normally it will be called automatically by the JRE when the user presses a key, with the key event passed in as the parameter.

Comment: So I tried it withough calling keyPressed but It still didnt work.. I dont mean to be a pain but If you could tell me where I am going rong it would be extremely useful :P

Comment: @Red_Hat I copied and pasted your program, made the necessary corrections, and got the square to move across the canvas. Check my new edit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I tried to do what you describe and came up with this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5629299/ , which still wont compile. Sorry again to bother you I am extremely new to Java and the concepts are confusing for someone who has done C or C++.

Comment: @Red_Hat I'd recommend looking up [abstract methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html). I clarified my language, "overriding" the methods is a better choice of words. I don't want to give an entire lesson on abstract methods, but essentially your syntax for implementing an interface and overriding its abstract methods is wrong. `keyReleased` and `keyTyped` are **methods**, not interfaces.